# Container class java

Tags: java, containers

I've got a problem and I don't understand how to solve it.

So I have 3 classes: first one is main, second one is book and the third one is a shelf which contains some books.

Book class

```
public class Book {
private String title;
private int year;
private String edition;

public Book(String title, int year, String edition) {
    this.title= title;
    this.year= year;
    this.edition = edition;
}

public Book(Book l)
{
    this.title = l.title;
    this.year = l.year;
    this.edition = l.edition;
}
```

Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Book one = new Book("Title1", first, 2014, "Edition1");
    Book two = new Book("Title2", second, 2013, "Edition2");
    Book three= new Book("Title3", third, 2015, "Edition3");
    Book four = new Book("Title4", fourth, 2015, "Edition4");

    Book[] v = new Book[3];
    v[0] = one;
    v[1] = two;
    v[2] = three;


    Shelf shelf= new Shelf();

   try{

    shelf.append(four);
   }(catch myException e)
    {
       System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Shelf class

```
public class Shelf {
private Book[] v;

public Shelf() 
{
    v = new Book[3];
}

public void append (Book x) throws myException
{
   if(x != null && v != null)
   {
    Book[] vAppend = new Book[v.length+1];

    for(int i=0; i<v.length; i++)  
    {
        vAppend[i] = new Book(v[i]);
    }
    vAppend[v.length] = new Book(x);
    v = vAppend;

   }
    throw new myException("Null");
}
```

How can I do the append method in shelf class? Obviously it give me NullPointerException because the array i'm using is null, but I don't know how to manage it.

One more question, how do I insert Book objects in Shelf class?

At first in the constructor I wrote " this.v = v " so when I declared a shelf object I passed its the v array in main class, which is not null, it worked but the exercise said not to do like this.

P.S. I have to do this exercise with normal array, I mean without arrayList, I still have to learn it.

Comment: as a side note, it doesn't make sense why you are explicitly using this `myException` class.  If you're going to hit a `NullPointerException` just let it happen, don't worry about specifically coding to throw your own custom NPE.

Comment: also, the `Book` constructors in `main` look wrong... `Book one = new Book("Title1", first, 2014, "Edition1");`.  Where is "first" coming from?

Comment: why do you say the array you are using is null? `v` is initialised in Shelf's constructor. Why do you initialise it to size 3?

Comment: Look at `java.util.ArrayList`, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `Shelf` constructor.

```
public Shelf()
{
    v = new Book[3];
}
```

You are initializing the array to be size 3, but you never fill it with books in the constructor.  So once you do `new Shelf()`  It has a Book array of size 3 with 3 null values in it.

So, you get a NPE because your `append(Book x)` method assumes that there are no null values in your Book array.

```
public void append(Book x)
{
    Book[] vAppend = new Book[v.length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
    {
        // ERROR: v.length is 3 but 
        // v[0], v[1], and v[2] will be null initially!!
        vAppend[i] = new Book(v[i]);
    }
    vAppend[v.length] = new Book(x);
    v = vAppend;
}
```

**To fix the issue:**
The simplest way is to change your constructor to make an array of size 0.  Then the rest of your code will handle it.

```
public Shelf()
{
    v = new Book[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you are expanding and copying every time a new book is inserted. This is not really necessary. Better is to have an initial capacity that is expanded only when the array is filled.

```
private static final int INCREMENT = 100;
private int capacity = 0;
private int size = 0;
private Book[] books = {};

public void append(Book book) {
    assert book != null;
    expandIfFull();
    books[size++] = book;
}

private void expandIfFull() {
    assert size <= capacity; 
    if (capacity == size) {
        capacity += INCREMENT;
        Book[] copy = new Book[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            copy[i] = books[i];
        books = copy;
    }
}
```

This has a performance advantage but it also seems to me to make your intent clearer by splitting the expansion code from the appending code. Having a separate method means that it can be called in your insert method as well.

You could reduce the expansion code using `Arrays` methods but I'm assuming the fact that you can't use Java collections implies that you need to do it manually.

You also asked about how to insert; I've added an example method for that. The key thing to remember is you need to shift the books after the insert position from the end first. Otherwise you'll just end up copying the same book through the rest of the array.

```
public void insert(int index, Book book) {
    assert index < size;
    expandIfFull();
    for (int i = size; i > index; i--)
        books[i] = books[i - 1];
    books[index] = book;
    size++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
public class Shelf {
    private Book[] v;

    public Shelf()
    {
        v = new Book[0];
    }

    public Shelf append (Book x) throws myException
    {
        if(x != null)
        {
            v = Arrays.copyOf(v, v.length + 1);
            v[v.length] = new Book(x);
            return this;
        }
        throw new myException("Null");
    }
```